# Cant return Directory in php

Tags: php, directory

Using this code:

```
$path = public_path().'/root';
$files = array();
$folders = array();

if (is_dir($path)) {
    $dirhandle = opendir($path);
        while (($dir = readdir($dirhandle)) !== false) {
            if(is_dir($dir) && $dir!= "." && $dir!= "..") {
                $folders[] = $dir;
            }
            else if(is_file($dir)) {
                $files[] = $dir;
            }
        }
       closedir();
}
return $folders;`
```

I can return the files inside the root folder but I can't return folders inside the root folder.

Inside the root folder, I have 3 folders and 4 files.
 Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: You can not return more than one variable out of a function, but you are collecting your data in two different arrays here. Use a multi-dimensional array instead, if you want to return both, something like `$entries['files']` and `$entries['folder']`, or similar.

Comment: use scandir(). That will give you an array with files and directories. If needed, cycle through the array and test if each element is a directory or not with is_dir().

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment...

```
$contents = scandir('.');  // Working directory is current dir

foreach($contents as $key => $entry){
  if(is_dir($entry)){
    $directories[] = $entry;
  } else {
    $files[] = $entry;
  }
}

echo('<pre>');
var_dump($directories, $files);
echo('</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will fix your problem.

```
$path = public_path().'/root';
foreach (glob($path . '/*') as $item) {
   if (is_dir($item)) {
      $folders[] = basename($item);
   } else {
      $files[] = basename($item);
   }
}

var_dump($folders);
var_dump($files);
```

more details about `glob` http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: tnx for this answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code snippet

```
$fnf = scandir('.');
$result = array();
$i=$j=0;
foreach($fnf as $key => $val){
  if(is_dir($val)){
     if($val == '..' || $val == '.') //Remove if you want to current and root directory (i.e . & ..)
        continue;
     $result['dir'][$i] = $val;
     $i++;
  } else {
    $result['files'][$j] = $val;
    $j++;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```